# Different themes for different sections

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, themes

Can I apply different styling themes to different sections of my Word document? So in the first section, I have it set to the "Default (Black and White)" theme, then I insert a section break, and want to use something entirely different for that section. The only way I can think to do this is to replicate all the styles which I will use and format them individually, which is quite clunky.

Comment: AFAIK themes do apply to the entire document. (Even using VBA you apply a them to a document, not a section). So it's either "work with separate documents and apply different themes to each of them, and fix up page numbering and headings when you're done". I can imagine that being quite a good way to do if the themes you want already exist, *and* all you need to do is deliver a PDF that you could put together from the various documents. Otherwise I think what you are doing is probably the only practical way forward - maybe using a macro to do mass updates on your styles would help.

Comment: @bibadia I think your comment above would be a good answer.